# Can a template hold a block in an {% if %} and {% else %} scenario

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I have a base template with a conditional header defined:

```
{% if blah %}
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Is there a technique/function available in templates that would allow you to set the title within a template which extends from the base?

Obviously you can't use a traditional block tag as they can only appear once, but is there something you could do to achieve effectively a `{% block title %}` for each `<h1>` so that whichever title was rendered from the `if` is changed by the extending template?

To be more specific, the template code I've got in the base is;

```
<div class="wrapper">
    {% if request.current_page.get_ancestors|length <= 1 %}
        {% block page_title %}
        <h1>{{ request.current_page.get_page_title }}</h1>
        {% endblock page_title %}
    {% else %}
        {% for ance in request.current_page.get_ancestors %}
            {% if ance.level == 1 %}
            {% block page_title %}
                <h1>{{ ance.get_page_title }}</h1>
            {% endblock page_title %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**Edit**

Full code for the base template; http://pastebin.com/cyWAiWn2

Full code for the extending template; http://pastebin.com/ThEqff47

The reason for this functionality requirement is that within django-cms I create a page and hook my application to that page. At that stage `{{ request.current_page.get_page_title }}` will just return the title of the django-cms page I have created.

If you've done something on that page which makes the hooked application send you to another view/template you don't actually change the page within django-cms so `get_page_title` is still the same, but the template you've now rendered will almost always have a different title.

Obviously you could include the new page title as a `<h2>` or whatever and sit it beneath the `<h1>` from `base_content.html` but the base title is usually superfluous to the required page content at that level.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one title block like so, then you can use a normal block tag in an extending template to override the title.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    {% block title %}
        {% if request.current_page.get_ancestors|length <= 1 %}
            <h1>{{ request.current_page.get_page_title }}</h1>
        {% else %}
            {% for ance in request.current_page.get_ancestors %}
                {% if ance.level == 1 %}
                    <h1>{{ ance.get_page_title }}</h1>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock title %}
</div>
```

I do not see the need for the two title blocks in your template, can you provide an example of an overriding template that would need to define two title blocks?

Comment: I've added two pastebin links to the templates. As you can see, the base template renders the page in two different ways depending on a page property. I don't think a single block is suitable for what I'm looking for.